# Highcharts Set data label border color for each pie slice

Tags: highcharts

I would like to be able to set the borders for the data labels of each slice of a pie chart independently. You can do this for each point in a [column or line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-box/) by entering it into the series data as shown, but I can't figure out how to make it work for the pie charts.

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 178.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
            y: 216.4,
            dataLabels: {
                borderColor: 'red',
                borderWidth: 2,
                padding: 5,
                shadow: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
```

Thanks

Comment: It works exactly the same way as you have in the example you posted. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3etkbmkf/ (just set pie chart type).

Comment: Thanks Pawel Fus. You are right. I had a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `plotOptions.pie` attributes like so:

```
 plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

See this [fadizzle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecau8Lzp/1/) .